# How to set Azure Functions to be disabled initially when deploy using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, azure-functions, serverless

How to set Azure Functions to be disabled initially when deploy using Visual Studio? I want to turn it on manually not automatically by the deployment.

Comment: Is it an option to use `disabled` property of `function.json`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference#function-code

Answer (score 2):

You could add `[Disable("settingname")]` attribute to your function and then set the app setting `settingname` to `true` before the deployment.

Set it to `false` when you need to run the functions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible. Once you deploy function app using Visual Studio, Azure portal puts such app into read only mode and restricts editing `function.json` which is otherwise used for enabling/ disabling individual function.

Comment: you can control whether `function.json` is read-only with the Application Settings using `FUNCTION_APP_EDIT_MODE` [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#functionappeditmode]